# System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.WriteObject ignores NonSerialized attribute while serializing

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

If i try to serialize an object of the following ClassToSerialize class with System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer

```
[DataContract,Serializable]
public class ClassToSerialize
{
    [NonSerialized] private bool _mf;
    public bool IsMf
    { 
        get { return _mf};
        set{ _mf = value;} 
    }

    [DataMember]
    public char PrimaryExc { get; set; }        
}

public class TestClass
{
    ClassToSerialize obj = new ClassToSerialize{PrimaryExchange = 'a', NoResults = true};
    var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(ClassToSerialize);
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

The return string still contains IsMf property and its value. The NOnSerialized attribute is ignored. Can someone please suggest what attribute to use when using DataContractJsonSerializer so as to not serialize some properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code worked for me (it's almost identical to your's with a few small compilation errors fixed):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new ClassToSerialize
        {
            PrimaryExc = 'a', 
            NoResults = true
        };

        var serializer 
            = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ClassToSerialize));

        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);

        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
    }
}

[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class ClassToSerialize
{
    [NonSerialized]
    private bool _mf;

    public bool IsMf
    {
        get { return _mf; }
        set { _mf = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public bool NoResults { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public char PrimaryExc { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

> `{"NoResults":true,"PrimaryExc":"a"}`

Comment: I upvoted Darin's reply because it is more accurate and complete and downvoted this one because it's misleading. Only members marked with [DataMember] are serialized the other ones are not. No need for [NonSerialized] which is as you noticed is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't contain it. You must be mistaken:

```
[DataContract]
public class ClassToSerialize
{
    [NonSerialized] 
    private bool _mf;
    public bool IsMf
    {
        get { return _mf; }
        set{ _mf = value;}  
    }

    [DataMember]
    public char PrimaryExc { get; set; }        
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new ClassToSerialize 
        {
            PrimaryExc = 'a', 
            IsMf = false
        };
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        serializer.WriteObject(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), obj);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"PrimaryExc":"a"}
```

Remark: You don't need the [`[Serializable]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) attribute on your class. That's only for [binary serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx).